# For a map $P^1 \to P^1$, the possible ramifications are limited by Riemann-Hurwitz and ...

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For a map $\phi : P^1 \to P^1$, the possible ramifications are limited by Riemann-Hurwitz (here saying that $2(deg \phi - 1) = \Sigma_{P \in P^1} (e_\phi(P) - 1)$) and the formula $\Sigma_{P \in \phi^{-1}(Q)} e_\phi(P) = \deg \phi$.

For example, if the degree of $\phi$ is 2, the only possibility is that there are two points of ramification, each ramified to order 2. Let's represent this by the ordered pair $(2,2)$. One can easily write down such a map, or guarantee its existence from Riemann Roch (a function in the space of global sections of the degree zero divisor $2P - 2Q$).

For higher degree maps, we can write down similar (finite) lists of possibilities: how many points are ramified, and what their ramifications are.
If $\deg = 3$, we have $(3,3)$ (which means two points in the domain are triply ramified), and $(2, 2, 2, 2)$ (meaning there are four points in the domain of ramification 2, each one is paired with some other unramified point that has the same image, everywhere else it is a 3-1 cover). The first one is easy to write down, the latter one I am unsure about.

My question is: Is there a function realizing $(2,2,2,2)$? Is there a function realizing every tuple arising in this way? Maybe it follows from Riemann-Roch somehow?

More thoughts about this:

It also seems like one could approach this via the function field, by adjoining n-th roots of elements of the form $t - a$ to try to produce prescribed ramification there. It's not at all clear to me what the ramification of the resulting map would look like - it should be interesting for me to work this out.

Comment: if you take two degree $3$ polynomials "at random", $f/g$ will have ramification type $(2,2,2,2)$ almost surely (the same can be said at any degree, add one pair every time you add $1$ to the degree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every ramification profile that satisfies the two conditions you stated (Riemann-Hurwitz and the degree bound on the ramification index) is possible.

Sketch of proof: the set of maps $\phi : \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $d$ is a Grassmannian $Gr(2,d+1)$: writing $\phi = \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ with $f(z),g(z)$ polynomials of degree $d$, we get a rank-2 subspace
$$\mathrm{span}(f(z),g(z)) \subset \{\text{degree $\leq d$ polynomials in } z\}.$$
In fact this space is unaffected by changing coordinates on the target $\mathbb{P}^1$. Conversely, given a rank-2 subspace, we can choose any basis for it to use as $f$ and $g$. This reconstructs $\phi$ *up to* changing coordinates on the target, which doesn't affect the ramification profile.

The condition "$\phi$ is (at least) simply ramified at $p$" is a codimension one condition on this $Gr(2,d+1)$, a divisor. This divisor is *ample* (it is a hyperplane section of $Gr(2,d+1)$ in the Plücker embedding), which means every positive-dimensional subvariety of $Gr(2,n)$ will intersect it.

This is enough to know that the profile of "all simply-ramified points" must be achievable: just intersect each of the subsets
$$\{\phi \text{ ramified at } p \} \subset Gr(2,d+1)$$
for the distinct points $p$. (Note that the dimension of $Gr(2,d+1)$ is $2(d-1)$, so we can force exactly the right number of points to be simply ramified.)

To get specific other profiles, the story is a morally similar but technically a little different -- I'm not sure if there's an easier answer than to use some amount of Schubert calculus / combinatorics. This is a computation in the cohomology ring $H^*(Gr(2,d+1))$ of $Gr(2,d+1)$, namely multiplying the classes of several of what are called (special) `Schubert varieties' -- these are very well studied and understood.

In this case, the classes corresponding to "having a specified ramification index at $p$" will always multiply to something nonzero in $H^*(Gr(2,d+1))$, which in particular implies that the locus corresponding to $\phi$ having a specified ramification profile is always nonempty.

For more sources, search for "the Wronski problem".

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer. One point that I don't understand clearly (but I think I should be able to) is why the condition of being at least simply ramified at p is a codimension one condition. I am thinking of the ramification condition at $p$ to mean that the order of the pullback of some local equation of $\phi(p)$ is $\geq 0$. If $\phi = [f_0 : f_1]$, then this means that $ord_p (f_1(p)f_0 - f_0(p)f_1) \geq 1$. I am not sure how to translate this in to a condition on the Grassmanian. Is there a better way to think about this?

Excited to learn about intersection theory eventually!

Comment: You may as well set $p=0$. Then the condition should be that $\mathrm{span}(f_0, f_1)$ intersects nontrivially $S = \mathrm{span}(z^2, \ldots, z^d)$. A generic $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^{d+1}$ will miss $S$ (which has dimension $d-1$). Asking it to meet it nontrivially is codimension 1: it is saying that $f_0, f_1, z^2, \ldots, z^d$ is not a basis (in coordinates, this is the vanishing of a determinant, i.e. one equation).

Comment: Very welcome! If you would like a source on intersection theory and/or Schubert calculus (a.k.a. intersection theory of $Gr(k,n)$), I recommend either Eisenbud and Harris's "3264" or Fulton's "Young Tableaux".

Comment: Just a remark: This is no longer true if you want to specify the type of ramification more precisely, i.e. if you specify in your ramification profile also how the ramification is diestributed among the points in the fiber (and not just the number of points in the preimage); e.g. the profile in your notation (3,3,3) of a degree 4 map can be realized by a covering where over each branch point three branches come together, but not as one where over one point three branches come together and over the other two points two branches each.

Comment: Ah, that is an interesting observation. So I can force $p,q$ to map with local degrees $d_p, d_q$, but I can't (necesarily) also get $p$ and $q$ to map to the same point, at least not easily. This is getting more into the realm of Hurwitz spaces than Schubert calculus.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong, as Jake Levinson points out.

So there is a simple minded answer to my question, which is no:

This is just because a rational (hence regular) function on $P^1$ is determined by its poles and zeros, so not all combinations of ramifications are possible.

Thanks Jake, I found my mistake:

I was assuming that for the ramification profiles $(3,2,2)$ and $(2,2,2,2)$, I could always apply a linear automorphism on the range to make the parts corresponding to $(2,2)$ in both be poles and zeros, and then apply a linear automorphism on the domain to bring the two divisors $2P + R - 2Q - S$ and $2P' + R' - 2Q' - S'$ into each other, and from that apply Riemann-Roch to limit the dimension of the space of permitted functions. Of course the problem now that I think through this more carefully is that I cannot interchange $2P + R - 2Q - S$ and $2P' + R' - 2Q' - S'$ freely in $P^1$.

Comment: I don't understand how this implies it...

Comment: @JakeLevinson Great, that is a much more interesting reality. I think I found my mistake.